# Preventing applications from creating folders in your documents folder

Tags: applications, uti

I have two applications (Microsoft RDP Client and Parallels Desktop) that insist on creating their own folders in my Documents folder. They use those to store user-specific files, settings, profiles and such.

My Documents folder is neatly organized and I don't want applications creating their folders in it. Parallels Desktop has a setting allowing me to change the path for its folder, but the Microsoft RDP client doesn't seem to.

Is there a straightforward way to prevent an application from automatically creating folders in `Documents`?

In my specific case, I'd be happy with a solution that prevents RDP Client from creating the directory altogether, e.g. by creating a hidden locked entry with the same name as the folder it wants to create.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I understand your frustration, but I suggest you just hide the offending folders from Finder, you can easily do that with the following terminal command:

```
chflags hidden ~/Documents/HideMe
```

Preventing those folders to be created is likely going to cause problems running those applications.

Answer (score 3):

1. Right click on folder you wish to have scrubbed from existence.
2. Click "Properties".
3. Click "Hidden".
4. Click "Apply".

Unfortunately this only hides it and does not remove it.  You will have to repeat this process for any folders created, but it seems to be a way to at least keep your documents folder organized to your liking.